# Firebase phone number authentication in xamarin.ios

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-authentication

Does firebase supports phone number authentication in xamarin.ios?? If yes then how to implement it? Phone number authentication using OTP send as SMS.

Comment: Xamarin has already bound Firebase Authentication (package = `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Auth`). Consult the Firebase docs for usage: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes it has Firebase authentication, but I cant find where Phone number authentication can be done using Firebase SDKs.

Comment: Ah... sorry I forgot, `FIRPhoneAuthProvider` is not bound by Xamarin's lbrary, but you can do it yourself as I am also using phone auth on Androd. I used Xamarin's source as a reference (`https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents`) and also disabled swizzling by default across all the firebase libaries so I am not sure if the automatic APN works or not, I just apply it manually (this is shown in Firebase's docs...)

Comment: There is an open issue on this: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/65

Comment: @SushiHangover I have checked this url - (https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents) in this on which component your were working as reference?

Comment: Firebase.auth is the project, but you need the entire repo in order to build the dependences

Comment: @SushiHangover i tried that but no success , can your give some other workaround solution?

Comment: Post another question with just your changes to the `ApiDefinition.cs` so I can can what you did...